# Keeping colorbar labels at old position when changing their value

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I recently started working with colorbars. I had a colorbar that looked like this:

[image]

Now I'd like to change all the values $x$ next to it, to $10^x$, but keep the new values at the original location of $x$. I tried to do that by using : `cbar.set_ticks([10**t for t in cbar.ax.get_yticks()])`

Now the colorbar code part looks like this:

```
kaart = ax.contourf(lons, lats, np.log10(Ui),cmap=plt.cm.BuGn, transform = ccrs.PlateCarree())
cbar =plt.colorbar(kaart)
cbar.set_label( label='Uncertainty in celcius', size = 20)
cbar.set_ticks([10**t for t in cbar.ax.get_yticks()])
```

But the resulting colorbar looks like :

[image]

How can I keep the labels at their original place?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to set a [tick formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html) that given the exponent creates a label of the desired form.

A better solution is to [use `locator=LogLocator()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_log.html) in the call to `contourf()`. With the [`LogLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator) you can specify for which multiples of 10 you want a subdivision. Default `subs=(1,)`: only at the exact powers of 10. Changing this to `subs=(1,2,)` would use powers of 10 and twice powers of 10.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator, LogFormatterMathtext
import numpy as np

lons = np.linspace(0, 50, 20)
lats = np.linspace(0, 40, 10)
Ui = np.power(10, np.random.uniform(-2.8, 0.4, size=(10, 20)))

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(16, 5))

kaart1 = ax1.contourf(lons, lats, np.log10(Ui), cmap='BuGn')
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(kaart1, ax=ax1)
cbar1.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: f'$10^{{{x:.1f}}}$')
ax1.set_title('Special purpose tick formatter')

kaart2 = ax2.contourf(lons, lats, Ui, locator=LogLocator(), cmap='BuGn')
cbar2 = plt.colorbar(kaart2, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('Default LogLocator')

kaart3 = ax3.contourf(lons, lats, Ui, locator=LogLocator(subs=(1, 2)), cmap='BuGn')
cbar3 = plt.colorbar(kaart3, ax=ax3)
cbar3.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(LogFormatterMathtext())
ax3.set_title('LogLocator(subs=(1, 2))')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: changing contourf colorbar]

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of the ticks doing that, so maybe:

```py
ticks = cbar.ax.get_yticks()
mylabels = [f'{10**t}' for t in ticks]
cbar.set_ticks(ticks, labels=mylabels)
```

However, if you are really plotting a logarithm of your data, consider contouring/pcolor on the original data and using LogNorm:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
data = 10**np.random.randn(10, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pc = ax.pcolormesh(data, norm=mcolors.LogNorm(vmin=10**-3, vmax=10**3))
fig.colorbar(pc)
plt.show()
```

[image: LogNorm example]

Comment: I just tried this approach with `contourf()` using `norm=LogNorm()` instead of `locator=LogLocator()`, and to my surprise, it also works there. But I didn't find a way to influence the number of subdivisions. E.g. `contourf(..., norm=LogNorm(), levels=20)` still only shows 4 color levels with my test data (`10**np.random.uniform(-2.8, 0.4, size=(10, 20))`).

Comment: Automatically choosing levels is tricky, and I think may have been buggy until recently with log norm.  However you can always manually specify the levels if you prefer.